# Maven release using Hudson. Release succeeds, But Hudson stays red

Tags: java, maven-2, hudson, release-management, maven-release-plugin

We are using the maven release plug-in on Hudson to automate the release process. When we do a release, the console log does say that the release was successful and the artifacts get deployed to the repository. But the hudson still stays red. when I look at hudson, the release is green and all other modules of the project stays red.

The project structure we have is.

```
             parent
               | -------- module 1
               | -------- module 2
```

Module 1 and Module 2 artifacts get deployed. all the tests passes. But when I look at hudson, it stays red.

When I look at the hudson  module console log, this is what I find,

```
Started
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.DownstreamBuildViewUpdateListener.onStarted(DownstreamBuildViewUpdateListener.java:76)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.DownstreamBuildViewUpdateListener.onStarted(DownstreamBuildViewUpdateListener.java:48)
    at hudson.model.listeners.RunListener.fireStarted(RunListener.java:139)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1243)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild.access$600(MavenBuild.java:71)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild$ProxyImpl2.close(MavenBuild.java:453)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.end(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:701)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:497)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:416)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1248)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:318)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:129)
```

What could be the reason. Any help would be appreciated. I want hudson to turn green.

Comment: What version of Hudson, plugin and Maven are you using?

Comment: Hudson version is 1.370. Maven version is 2.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you upgraded the downstream build view plugin? I was having this problem and reported it, and it got fix in the latest version. See http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-7691